# Choosing the right data structure enum/struct/class?

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures

I am parsing a file that looks like this:

```
test_data = {
{
  id = '001-000505',
  cnv = {
    e9 = 0,
    i6 = 0,
  },
  rel = {
    rs10850985 = '-',
    rs38932097 = '-',
    rs5030655 = '-',
    rs10655852 = '-',
    rs28371725 = '-',
  },
  result = '*5/*5',
  gt = {
    rs31080985 = { '-', '-' },
    rs16947 = { '-', '-' },
    rs3892097 = { '-', '-' },
    rs503350655 = { '-', '-' },
    rs50530865 = { '-', '-' },
    rs5030656 = { '-', '-' },
    rs106371706 = { '-', '-' },
    rs59421388 = { '-', '-' },
    rs7693258 = { '-', '-' },
    rs28371725 = { '-', '-' },
  },
},
{
  id = '004-AATTGG',
  cnv = {
    e9 = 1,
    i6 = 1,
  },
  rel = {
    rs1080985 = '>>',
    rs3892097 = '>>',
    rs505306d55 = '>>',
    rs1065852 = '>>',
    rs2837d1725 = '>>',
  },
  result = '*1/*5',
  gt = {
    rs10830985 = { 'C', 'C' },
    rs164947 = { 'C', 'C' },
    rs3892097 = { 'G', 'G' },
    rs5030e655 = { 'T', 'T' },
    rs5030865 = { 'G', 'G' },
    rs5030656 = { 'AAG', 'AAG' },
    rs1065852 = { 'C', 'C' },
    rs28371706 = { 'C', 'C' },
    rs59421388 = { 'G', 'G' },
    rs769258 = { 'G', 'G' },
    rs28371725 = { 'G', 'G' },
  },
},
{
  id = '003-0300101',
  cnv = {
    e9 = 1,
    i6 = 1,
  },
  rel = {
    rs1080985 = '>>',
    rs3892097 = '>>',
    rs50530655 = '>>',
    rs10365852 = '>>',
    rs283271725 = '<<',
  },
  result = '*41/*5',
  gt = {
    rs1080985 = { 'C', 'C' },
    rs16947 = { 'T', 'T' },
    rs3892097 = { 'G', 'G' },
    rs5030655 = { 'T', 'T' },
    rs5030865 = { 'G', 'G' },
    rs5030656 = { 'AAG', 'AAG' },
    rs1065852 = { 'C', 'C' },
    rs28371706 = { 'C', 'C' },
    rs593421388 = { 'G', 'G' },
    rs7659258 = { 'G', 'G' },
    rs28371725 = { 'A', 'A' },
  },
},
{
  id = '007-CCAA',
  cnv = {
    e9 = 1,
    i6 = 1,
  },
  rel = {
    rs1080985 = '>>',
    rs38922097 = '>>',
    rs50350655 = '>>',
    rs1065852 = '>>',
    rs283371725 = '<<',
  },
  result = '*41/*5',
  gt = {
    rs1080985 = { 'C', 'C' },
    rs16947 = { 'T', 'T' },
    rs3892097 = { 'G', 'G' },
    rs50350655 = { 'T', 'T' },
    rs50350865 = { 'G', 'G' },
    rs5030656 = { 'AAG', 'AAG' },
    rs106235852 = { 'C', 'C' },
    rs28371706 = { 'C', 'C' },
    rs59421388 = { 'G', 'G' },
    rs769258 = { 'G', 'G' },
    rs28371725 = { 'A', 'A' },
  },
},
{
  id = '001-000105',
  cnv = {
    e9 = 1,
    i6 = 1,
  },
  rel = {
    rs1080985 = '>>',
    rs38392097 = '>>',
    rs5030655 = '>>',
    rs10565852 = '>>',
    rs283371725 = '>>',
  },
  result = '*1/*5',
  gt = {
    rs10820985 = { 'C', 'C' },
    rs16947 = { 'C', 'C' },
    rs32892097 = { 'G', 'G' },
    rs53030655 = { 'T', 'T' },
    rs50303865 = { 'G', 'G' },
    rs50530656 = { 'AAG', 'AAG' },
    rs1065852 = { 'C', 'C' },
    rs283751706 = { 'C', 'C' },
    rs59421388 = { 'G', 'G' },
    rs769258 = { 'G', 'G' },
    rs28371725 = { 'G', 'G' },
  },
},
```

i need to parse all this data and capture it in some kind of data structure.

here is what i came up with:

```
 struct LuaStructure
    {
        public string id { get; set; }

        public struct cnv
        {
            public string e9 { get; set; }
            public string x9 { get; set; }
            public string i6 { get; set; }
        }
        public struct rel
        {
            public string rs1080985 { get; set; }
            public string rs3892097 { get; set; }
            public string rs5030655 { get; set; }
            public string rs1065852 { get; set; }
            public string rs28371725 { get; set; }
        }

        public string result { get; set; }

        public struct gt
        {
            public string rs1080985 { get; set; }
            public string rs16947 { get; set; }
            public string rs3892097 { get; set; }
            public string rs5030655 { get; set; }
            public string rs5030865 { get; set; }
            public string rs5030656 { get; set; }
            public string rs1065852 { get; set; }
            public string rs28371706 { get; set; }
            public string rs59421388 { get; set; }
            public string rs769258 { get; set; }
            public string rs28371725 { get; set; }
        }

    }
```

i dont think this is the right solution because i would want to say

```
string somestring=LuaStructure.gt.rs1080985;
```

this would not be possible because i would need to first declare;

```
LuaStructure somestructure = new LuaStructure;
```

then i would need to do

```
LuaStructure.gt somestructuregt = new LuaStructure.gt;
```

I dont want to have to go through this entire process

what combination of class/struct/enum do i need to capture the data that i want?

Comment: That structure is God awful. Good luck... **Have you considered using property initializers during object creation?**

Comment: @Yuck you're darn right it's awful can you please suggest something more usable :)

Comment: @yuck can you please show me what you mean? i dont understand how to do initializers for nested data

Comment: `new SomeObject { PropertyA = "", PropertyB = 1234, NestedObject = new AnotherObject { InnerValue = 123 } }` This isn't really an answer so I apologize for posting it in the comments.

Comment: @Yuck should the object be a class? could you please show me what you mean in an answer? thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

You aren't going to benefit from doing this in `struct`s since the properties/types will require explicit parsing and assignment. I tend to avoid this but you may actually benefit from using RegEx or basic string manipulation to transform your input into JSON since the format is fairly close. Doing so, you could at least leverage existing parsers to handle the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: thanks so much for your answer. can you show me how i can do this with regex?

Comment: That seems to fall slightly out of the scope of your question (so you'll need to ask another one after trying to figure it out yourself). Besides, you don't want my advice on RegEx (I know just a little more than enough to make a mess for the person that follows after me). Take a look at the JSON spec. The formatting is a near match and simple string manipulation would likely do the trick.

Comment: thank you. can you please tell me how it's a match? it doesnt seem like it would be a match to me

Comment: I said it's a *near* match. Replace the `=` with `:` and the single quotes with double quotes and it looks a lot like a series of JSON collections of collections (of collections).

Comment: the only thing i need to do is replace the semicolon and quotes? and then it will be exactly json?

Comment: I didn't say that. I said it will provide syntax *like* JSON. With a few tweaks it should generally be parseable.

Comment: gotcha! can you please suggest to me i can structure my data. i think i will stick to what i have now, but i would like to know how to do the structs

Comment: I personally don't see any value in using structs in this situation. They are value types and this seems more like a case for reference types (since your data will contain reference types anyway in the form of collections). One general problem that any JSON parser I've used will have with your existing type definitions is, for example, the test data at `/test_data/gt/rs31080985` is a list not a `string`. It won't parse as a string unless you do it yourself.

Comment: i forgot to mention that i have a library that already parses this data :)

Comment: That kind of kills the value and intrigue to the question. The first part to my last comment is still valid though. `struct` won't buy you anything here.